# make sense of index terms in dl.acm.org website

Tags: research-process, computer-science, reading

I am a graduate student. I plan to submit my master project this year.

While browsing relevant papers in my research field, I wonder how making sense of index terms on the site dl.acm.org

For an example, consider this link: [dl.acm.org](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1937055.1937058).

Comment: What is your question? The tags are author supplied when the paper is submitted. The system is hierarchical. The tags are used to help readers find relevant papers, much as the tags used on this site. They are also used to help in finding editors/reviewers as appropriate. See this: https://dl.acm.org/ccs

Comment: Did you do Google search on "ACM index terms"?

Comment: Thank you so much @Buffy.

Comment: @scaaahu I did, but there but my query was not relevant as your I guessed. thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to what is done at other professional societies that publish journals, the ACM has a [classification system](https://dl.acm.org/ccs) for submitted papers. Authors classify their own submissions. The system is hierarchical to provide a bit of granularity.

Potential readers use the assigned tags to find articles relevant to their own interests, and the editors use them to assign area editors and reviewers.

The tags used on this site are a bit similar in terms of finding questions related to a readers interest.